# Scrolling Toolbar in DrawerLayout in CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a problem with the below layout structure:

```
<CoordinatorLayout>
    <AppBarLayout>
        <Toolbar>
    </AppBarLayout>

    <DrawerLayout
        app:layout_behavior="appbarScrollingBehavior">
        <ViewPager>
        <ListView>
    </DrawerLayout>
</CoordinatorLayout>
```

Everything works fine, but there is a problem with the scrolling of the `AppBarLayout`. Namely, the `ListView` acting as a side drawer is "pushed" downwards by the height of the `Toolbar`. This causes the last element to be visible only when the `Toolbar` is completely collapsed :-(

Any ideas why this is happening? I already tried replacing the `ListView` with a `RecyclerView`, but it did not help. It seems that the `CoordinatorLayout` is measuring children first and only then moving them according to the `Behaviors`.